# How to call Mapping solidity where KeyValue is Enum and ValueType is Struct in Ether Js?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, solidity, chai, ethers.js

I'm confused about how do I call the solidity mapping for Unit Testing needs on Ether Js and Chai Js. Here's the Solidity code I'm using

```
pragma solidity 0.8.17;

struct NftSpec {
        uint256 supplyLimit;
        uint256 cost;
        uint256 maxMintAmountPerTx;
        uint256 alreadyMinted;
        bool toggle;
    }
enum MintingFeature {
        publicMinting,
        whitelistMinting,
        giftMinting
    }

mapping(MintingFeature => NftSpec) public feature;

constructor() ERC721("Testing", "TSNG") {
        feature[MintingFeature.publicMinting] = NftSpec(2000, 0.02 ether, 3, 0, false );
        feature[MintingFeature.whitelistMinting] = NftSpec(1000, 0.015 ether, 1, 0, false );
    }
```

I want to make sure that the value matches with value in the constructor. But I have a problem to call `feature` mapping directly using Ether Js.

Answer (score 1):

You can create getter function to test this.

```
function getMapping() public view returns(NftSpec memory) {
    return feature[MintingFeature.publicMinting];     
}
```

will return full mapping:

```
const value = await yourContractInstance.getMapping()
console.log(value)
```

to ensure that value matches:

```
expect(await value.supplyLimit).to.eq(2000)
```

To call mapping directly:

```
const temp = (await mappingContract.feature(0)).supplyLimit
console.log(temp)
```

It appears to pass mapping key we need to use () instead of [], 0 is your enum (MintingFeature.publicMinting)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but can we call mapping directly without get function?

Comment: I was trying to write this, but nothing worked, then i googled but there was no examples either, therefore i think this is the best approach.

Comment: I've edited my answer, its possible to call mapping directly